# Rails 4 error - rails Couldn't find User with 'id'=index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I'm trying to follow CyberDude's advice in this post:

[Defining Roles with Rolify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950172/defining-roles-with-rolify)

I'm getting stuck at the part where I make an index for users in the user/views file.

I am getting an error that says:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=index

Extracted source (around line #69):
67
68
69
70
71
72

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
```

I can't understand this error message. Others with similar messages seem to have problems arising in other actions (like #show) where an :id is required. I think index doesn't need and id (but I'm not sure about that).

I have:

User's controller (I also have a folder in my controllers called "user" and it has controllers for regirations and omniauth callbacks):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :finish_signup, :destroy]

  def index
    # if params[:approved] == "false"
    #   @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    # else
      @users = User.all
    # end

  end

  # GET /users/:id.:format
  def show
    # authorize! :read, @user
  end

  # GET /users/:id/edit
  def edit
    # authorize! :update, @user
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/:id.:format
  def update
    # authorize! :update, @user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        sign_in(@user == current_user ? @user : current_user, :bypass => true)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET/PATCH /users/:id/finish_signup
  def finish_signup
    # authorize! :update, @user


    if request.patch? && params[:user] #&& params[:user][:email]
      if @user.update(user_params)
        @user.skip_reconfirmation!
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.'
        # redirect_to [@user, @user.profile || @user.build_profile]
        # sign_in_and_redirect(@user, :bypass => true)
      else
        @show_errors = true
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/:id.:format
  def destroy
    # authorize! :delete, @user
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      # params.require(:user).permit(policy(@user).permitted_attributes)
      accessible = [ :first_name, :last_name, :email, :avatar, {role_ids: []} ] # extend with your own params
      accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
      # accessible << [:approved] if user.admin
      params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
    end

end
```

I have a users index view:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%">
    <% Users.each do |user| %>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <%= link_to "#{user.full_name}", user %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <%= link_to "#{user.email}", user %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <%= link_to "edit", edit_user_path(user) %>
            </div>
    </div> 
    <% end %>
```

When I try this, I get the error I posted above.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong, or decipher the error message?

Comment: it seems like you are calling the show action to find where user id = "index" .which means you are not calling the index action.

Comment: from here: `before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :finish_signup, :destroy]`
it doesn't make sense to do set_user for index action. index is listing for all users. take out :index. you're right, index action doesn't need an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your error is occuring because `:index` is in `before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :finish_signup, :destroy]`. Simply remove `:index` from the list and that should take care of this error. The `params` hash does not contain an `:id` key on the `index` route. Check out [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on Rails routing.

The `index` action is used, in this case, to grab all of the users so that they can be displayed on your index page. For example in one of my apps I have the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # omitted code

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Also just remove the `:index` action from the bellow code:
`before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :finish_signup, :destroy]`

, actually before calling any action in your controller a private function called "def set_user" is invoked and that cause the problem in your index action. You may have to rethink about the logic you are working on.

```
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Comment: @user2860931 : thanks for the UP then=> DOWN, hope your problem solved :)

Comment: Not intentional - just that i was following the other answer in solving this. its the same answer though, so thank you