# Rails 4 - Couldn't find OrgChecklist with 'id'=index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, controller

I generated a scaffold using the rails generator, and created the controller below.

When I try to check if it works, I get an error message that says:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /org_checklists/index
Couldn't find OrgChecklist with 'id'=index
```

I was getting the same error recently (question below) and the solution was to remove `:index` from the `before action`. However, this controller doesn't include that action in the `before action`.

[Rails 4 error - rails Couldn't find User with 'id'=index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518958/rails-4-error-rails-couldnt-find-user-with-id-index)

```
class OrgChecklistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_org_checklist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /org_checklists
  # GET /org_checklists.json
  def index
    @org_checklists = OrgChecklist.all
    authorize @org_checklists
  end

  # GET /org_checklists/1
  # GET /org_checklists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /org_checklists/new
  def new
    @org_checklist = OrgChecklist.new
  end

  # GET /org_checklists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /org_checklists
  # POST /org_checklists.json
  def create
    @org_checklist = OrgChecklist.new(org_checklist_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @org_checklist.save
        format.html { redirect_to @org_checklist, notice: 'Org checklist was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @org_checklist }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @org_checklist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /org_checklists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /org_checklists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @org_checklist.update(org_checklist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @org_checklist, notice: 'Org checklist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @org_checklist }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @org_checklist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /org_checklists/1
  # DELETE /org_checklists/1.json
  def destroy
    @org_checklist.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to org_checklists_url, notice: 'Org checklist was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_org_checklist
      @org_checklist = OrgChecklist.find(params[:id])
      authorize @org_checklist
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def org_checklist_params
      params[:org_checklist].permit(:organisation_id, :payment_method, :interests_set )
    end
end
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/org_checklists/index` corresponds to the `show` action in Rails, and it requires you to send a valid `id` to get the record from the database.

Since, you are passing `index` instead of `id`, so Rails is trying to use `index` to get a record form the database, and since it can't find one, so it gives you: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /org_checklists/index`

In order to rectify this, you need to pass a valid `id` like `/org_checklists/5`, and it will send you the show page for the record with id 5.

Note: if you are trying to access the `index` page, you just need to call `/org_checklists/`, and that's it; Rails will send you the index page, you do not need to explicitly mention `index` at the end. This is the essence to RESTful web services.