# Rails 4 - Rolify - how to assign a scoped role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I'm trying to figure out how to assign a role to a user in Rails 4, using rolify.

My use case is:

I want to assign global roles to users who operate the app.

I want to assign scoped roles to all customers. Each customer belongs to an organisation. Any role they are assigned will be confined to the organisation they belong to.

How can I achieve this in rails? At this stage, I'm stuck with the logic of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the docs [here](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#4-add-a-role-to-a-user). It has examples to define roles scoped to resource instance and resource class.

To define a global role:

```
customer = Customer.find(1)
customer.add_role :admin
```

To define a role scoped to a resource instance:

```
customer = Customer.find(2)
customer.add_role :moderator, Organization.first // you are looking for this
```

To define a role scoped to a resource class:

```
customer = Customer.find(3)
customer.add_role :moderator, Organization
```

Comment: thanks- I've seen the docs. I can't figure out how to implement that in the code. I don't know how to dynamically constrain the Organisation attribute to the relevant organisation. I don't know if I need to define a new controller action to assign a role - and if I do, I don't know which controller to put the action in

Comment: When they create an account. I have setout the full context here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810323/rails-4-rolify-setting-scoped-roles